# CORS Error and 'Failed to load response data' during JavaScript fetch request to Flask server

Tags: http, flask, cors, fetch-api, flask-cors

I have a Flask server running on my local machine and a frontend JavaScript application that sends a GET request to this server. The server is supposed to make a request to an external API and print the response. However, I am not seeing any output in my terminal or in my browser's console. Instead, I'm encountering a CORS error in my console.

Here's the relevant Flask server code:

```
@app.route('/news', methods=['GET'])
def get_news():
    symbol = request.args.get('symbol')
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.marketaux.com/v1/news/all?symbols={symbol}&language=en&api_token={api_token}")
    print(response.json())
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

And here's the JavaScript code that sends the GET request to the Flask server:

```
document.getElementById('stock-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the form from submitting normally
    let symbol = document.getElementById('symbol').value;

    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/news?symbol=${symbol}`, { mode: 'cors' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('result').textContent = `The average sentiment for ${symbol} is ${data.average_sentiment}.`;
        });
});
```

Upon submitting the form in the JavaScript application, I encounter a CORS error in my browser's console and see no output in my terminal where I'm running the Flask server. I would expect to see the JSON response from the external API in both places.

I have checked the following:

1. The Flask server is running and accessible from the browser.
2. The JavaScript code is correctly making a request to the Flask server (I see the request in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools).
3. The symbol variable in the JavaScript code is correctly populated with the value from the form.
4. The external API is working and I can make requests to it using Postman.

How can I handle the CORS error and debug why the Flask server is not returning any output in the terminal or displaying the expected response in the browser's console? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.